Starting a JAVA application on a network drive using another Java application with OpenJDK and JavaFX
I'm trying to start a jar file on a network drive from another application. With Java 1.8 this works without any problems. When switching to OpenJDK plus JavaFX, the start of the program is delayed by 10-20 seconds.
The problem is that it only works if JavaFX is also on the network drive. Then all modules have to be loaded via the network, which takes a lot of time.
Via batch file it works with the local javaFX installation:
java --module-path="%JAVA_FX%\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar myApplcationOnNetworkfolder.jar

But in the startApplication.jar the following code doesn´t work:
String cmd = "java --module-path=\"%JAVA_FX%\\lib\" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar myApplicationonNetworkfolder.jar";
String[] env = {""};
String directory = "network-folder";
if (directory != null) {
    File dir = new File(directory);
    if (dir.exists()) {
          Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, env, dir);
}}

It works with the following cmd line instead:
String cmd = "java --module-path lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar myApplicationonNetworkfolder.jar";

This works if JavaFX is installed on the network drive in the target folder. But it needs a lot of time.
How does the cmd string have to be adjusted so that it also works with %JAVA_FX%?
